# Selecting specific pieces of information from a text file and converting them to an array/list in python

Tags: python

I have this project that I have to code in Python but it's extremely hard for a total beginner. Basically, I've never programmed in python and have only begun google learning it since yesterday, so I thought maybe you guys could help with it because I can't even begin to solve this.

I am given an initial textfile, let's call it input.txt, which has the following data in the following fashion:

```
Thomas Hales
12 2345 
45 6780
63 3210
Peter Lebones
10 15430
11  1230
23 3450
John White
2 12130
11 32410
15 4520
```

There are names given and numbers under them. The numbers in the left column are simply identification numbers for the purposes of this problem. The numbers in the right column are money amounts that the people have invested in a bank let's say.

I'm supposed to take all of the data in the text file, manipulate it in ways, then make a new text file (all this is done by the script run by python) called output.txt
that for the above examples, contains this:

```
Thomas Hales 45
Peter Lebones 10
John White 11
```

what I have this far (but it's not working. at all. plus it's a total mess, and I did it with the help of somebody, who also doesn't really know what he's doing):

```
import sys
import subprocess
import re
import string


try:
    fread=open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()
except IOError:
    print "There is no file like that!"
    sys.exit()
except IndexError:
    print "There is no argumentum given"
alpha = string.ascii_letters
writeout=open("result.txt","w")
inputarray=fread.readlines()
for ... in inputarray: # not sure what goes in the "..." part
    array=inputarray.split('\n')
for i in range(len(array)-1):
    if array[i].isalpha():
    writeout.write(array[i]+" ")

fread.close()
writeout.close()
```

So basically, I am given a text file. I am then supposed to, for each person, select their highest investment, and associate the number in the left column with said highest investment. Then I'm supposed to make the script make an output.txt which contains the name of each person and the "Id number" of their highest investment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that when a line starts with a number, we have an investment, otherwise a name.

Each time you find a name, write out the previous name and the highest investment identifier:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as inputfile, open("result.txt","w") as outputfile:
    name = None
    investment_id = max_investment = 0
    for line in inputfile:
        if not line.strip(): continue  # skip empty lines

        if not line[:1].isdigit():  # name
            if name and investment_id: 
                # write previous name
                outputfile.write('{} {}\n'.format(name, investment_id))
            name = line.strip()
            investment_id = max_investment = 0

        else:
            id, investment = [int(i) for i in line.split()]
            if investment > max_investment:
                max_investment = investment
                investment_id = id

    if name and investment_id: 
        # write last name
        outputfile.write('{} {}\n'.format(name, investment_id))
```

For your example input, this writes:

```
Thomas Hales 45
Peter Lebones 10
John White 11
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The only thing is now I try to run it with execfile("filename.py", 'input.txt') but it says TypeError must be dict not str. Normally I know it's better to run as python filename.py 'input.txt' but actually, I'm running Windows 7 and I was screwing around for an hour yesterday trying to open any files with python file.py and nothing worked. The file is in the same path as the python.exe so not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Ah I just read you cannot pass arguments with execfile... but I can't get it to open the the script the traditional python script.py arg1 way, and subprocess isn't working either... I can run the file with execfile but then it says it's missing an argument...

Comment: `subprocess` should work just fine on Windows. Make sure you use the *full* path for the file.

Comment: Allright I got it working. Apparently, through cmd (and not directly through python.exe) it worked. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Ah just one more thing, if there is an empty line right after the names (like Thomas Hales and then there is a line of nothing and then the numbers) then the program doesn't seem to work, even though my task asks me to make it work with however many empty lines. Does this require drastic changes? Also, can I accept answers without logging in? I'm trying to give you credit here but I don't have an acc.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this basic recipe for processing a file line by line will help get you started on the right foot.

```
import sys

file_name = sys.argv[1]

# This takes care of closing the file after we're done processing it.
with open(file_name) as file_handle:

    # Once we have a file handle, we can iterate over it.
    for line in file_handle:

        # This is where your real programming logic will go.
        # For now, we're just printing the input line.
        print line,
```

I suspect you might also find `split()` to be useful, because it will allow you to break the numeric lines apart. For example, you could try this to experiment with how it works:

```
parts = line.split()
print parts
```

Answer (score 1):

using the python re module may give you a nice launching platform, simply breaking down the lines into something you can iterate over.

```
>>> results = re.findall("(\w+) (\w+)",buff,re.S)
[('Thomas', 'Hales'), ('12', '2345'), ('45', '6780'), ('63', '3210'), ('Peter', 'Lebones'), ('10', '15430'), ('23', '3450'), ('John', 'White'), ('2', '12130'), ('11', '32410'), ('15', '4520')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   with open("input.txt", "r") as inp, open("output.txt", "w") as out:
       data = inp.readlines()
       for i in xrange(0, len(data), 4):
           name = data[i].strip()
           maxi = 0
           true_code = 0
           for item in data[i+1: i+4]:
              code, bal = item.strip().split(" ")
              code, bal = int(code), int(bal)
              if bal >= maxi:
                  maxi = bal
                  true_code = code
           out.write("%s %s" %(name, true_code))
```

Comment: This gives a "need more than 1 value to unpack" error but thanks.

Comment: May be due to more than one space character between code and balance e.g. 11__1230 instead of 11_1230